# How to prove the equivalence of Wigner distribution function expressions?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

I'm currently going through Goodman's Introduction to Fourier Optics, Fourth Edition and I'm at the Wigner distribution function section, where he states the definition:

$$W_{g}(x,y;f_{x},f_{y}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x + \Delta x/2, y + \Delta y/2) g^{*}(x - \Delta x/2, y - \Delta y/2)\times e^{-2\pi j (f_{x}\Delta x + f_{y}\Delta y)} d\Delta x d\Delta y.$$

He then goes on to say that by replacing $g$ and $g^{*}$ with their Fourier integrals, using the shift theorem and the sifting property of delta functions, we can obtain the equivalent expression:

$$W_{g}(x,y;f_{x},f_{y}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(f_{x} + \Delta f_{x}/2, f_{y} + \Delta f_{y}/2) G^{*}(f_{x} - \Delta f_{x}/2, f_{y} - \Delta f_{y}/2)\times e^{2\pi j (x\Delta f_{x} + y\Delta f_{y})} d\Delta f_{x} d\Delta f_{y},$$

where $G$ is the Fourier transform of $g$. For a generic function the Fourier transform used is:

$$G(f_{x}, f_{y}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y) e^{-2\pi j (f_{x}x+f_{y}y)}dxdy$$

I've been trying to derive this result by attempting what he says to do, but have so far failed. I think I might be missing a substitution trick somewhere. I've also searched for other sources where this equivalence could be proven, but in the ones I have found, either both expressions are stated as definitions, or the equivalence result is just stated but never proven.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: I've edited the post. I hope this is what you meant @CosmasZachos.

Comment: Don't you mean $(\Delta f_{x}, \Delta x)$ as the active Fourier conjugate variables?

If I understand correctly, I should use the Fourier integrals of $g$ and $g^{*}$ where $\Delta x$ is my active variable and $x$ is the shift?

Comment: Yes on your question. [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution#Definition_and_meaning).

Comment: In 1D. I have $g(x+\Delta x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(f_{x})e^{2\pi jx f_{x}}e^{2\pi j \Delta x f_{x}} df_{x}$ and $g^{*}(x-\Delta x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G^{*}(f_{x})e^{2\pi jx f_{x}}e^{2\pi j \Delta x f_{x}} df_{x}$ (This is with $\Delta x$ being my space variable, $f_{x}$ is the corresponding frequency variable and $x$ is the shift.). But then I have to combine them with the outside integral. Could you please show me some calculations? 1D case is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a homework problem. In any case, for
$$
G(k) = \int \!\! dx ~ e^{2\pi j xk}~ g(x) \qquad \leadsto G^*(k) = \int \!\! dx ~ e^{-2\pi j xk}~ g^*(x), \leadsto \\ 
g(x+u/2)= \int \!\! dk' ~ e^{-2\pi j k' (x+u/2)}~ G(k'), \qquad g^*(x+u/2)= \int \!\! dk'' ~ e^{2\pi j k'' (x-u/2)}~ G^*(k''),
$$
so that, substituting in *W*,
$$
W(x;k)=  \int \!\! du   \int \!\! dk'   \int \!\! dk'' ~  e^{2\pi j( k'x+k'u/2-k''x +k''u/2- ku )} G(k') G^*(k'') \\
=   \int \!\! dk'   \int \!\! dk'' ~\delta\left (k-\frac{k'+k''}{2}\right )  ~e^{2\pi jx( k'-k'')} G(k') G^*(k'') \\
=  \int \!\! dw    ~  e^{2\pi jxw } G(k+w/2) G^*(k-w/2)~.
$$

Comment: I don't know why but for some reason I didn't want to combine the exponential terms. I thought I needed to generate different delta functions to pair with $G$ and $G^{*}$. Anyways, thank you!